# Turtle onclic doesn't work as expected, moving object that was not clicked

Tags: python-3.x, graphics

Want to make a ball to change trajectory when I click on it. But in my case when I click on some ball, movement not always happens on the ball that was clicked but on another one. Tried to change place for onclic method, but always the same. print shows that function is called for wrong object. Don't know how to make it right.

```
import random
import turtle

def my_function(x, y):
  print(x, y)
  xd[index] = -xd[index]
  print (myballs)

window = turtle.Screen()
window.delay(5)
message = turtle.Turtle()
message.hideturtle()
MAXX, MAXY = window.screensize()
BALLSIZE = 1
border = turtle.Turtle()
border.hideturtle()
border.speed(0)
border.up()
border.goto(MAXX, MAXY)
border.down()
border.pensize(1)
border.color('red')
border.goto(MAXX, -MAXY)
border.goto(-MAXX, -MAXY)
border.goto(-MAXX, MAXY)
border.goto(MAXX, MAXY)



balls = []
balls.append(turtle.Turtle())
balls.append(turtle.Turtle())


x = [0] * len(balls)
y = [0] * len(balls)
xd = [0] * len(balls)
yd = [0] * len(balls)
for myballs in balls:
    x, y = random.randint(-MAXX + 1, MAXX - 1), random.randint(-MAXY + 1, MAXY - 1)
    myballs.hideturtle()
    myballs.speed(0)
    myballs.up()
    myballs.shapesize(BALLSIZE)
    myballs.shape('circle')
    myballs.goto(x, y)
    myballs.showturtle()
    index = balls.index(myballs)
    speed = 1
    xd[index] = speed
    yd[index] = speed
    myballs.onclick(my_function)

while True:
    for myballs in balls:


        index = balls.index(myballs)
        x, y = myballs.pos()

        if x+BALLSIZE*10 >= MAXX or x-BALLSIZE*10 <= -MAXX:
            xd[index] = -xd[index]

        if y+BALLSIZE*10 >= MAXY or y-BALLSIZE*10 <= -MAXY:
            yd[index] = -yd[index]


        x = x + xd[index]
        y = y + yd[index]

        myballs.goto(x, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, import math module:

```
import math
```

then change your function to this:

```
def my_function(x, y):
print(x, y)
for i,ball in enumerate(balls):
    ball_x, ball_y = ball.pos()
    if math.hypot(abs(x-ball_x), 
                  abs(y-ball_y)) < BALLSIZE*10:
        xd[i] = -xd[i]
        print(i, ball)
        return
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works for me. Could you please tell me if I choose correct place for onclic initialization or better to set put it elsewhere ?

Comment: It's correct, I forgot to place "return" at the end. Now fixed.